# Adding conditional breakpoint in NodeJS debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

The node.js `help` command outputs the following:

```
debug> help
Commands: run (r), cont (c), next (n), step (s), out (o), backtrace (bt), setBreakpoint (sb), clearBreakpoint (cb),
watch, unwatch, watchers, repl, restart, kill, list, scripts, breakOnException, breakpoints, version
```

I can add a new breakpoint using `setBreakpoint`:

```
debug> setBreakpoint(12)
...
```

But can I make it conditional? For example:

```
*only if `foo() === true`, stop here*
```

The alternative would be to add it as `if` in the script:

```
if (foo()) { debugger; }
```

Is this possible via NodeJS debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved by using `watchers`. I am not too familiar with its use cases or syntax so I don't have any examples.

The documentation seems to describe this use with variable names. It may also depend on what version of node.js we are talking about.

https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_info

Comment: Hmm, using `watch` you display the variable value, instead of adding a breakpoint. Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.defineProperty`. For example:

```
function setter () { debugger; }

Object.defineProperty(Math, 'name', { set: setter });
```

will add a debugger statement if the `name` property is set on the `Math` object.

**References**

- [MDN: Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [A List Apart: Advanced Debugging With JavaScript](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/advanced-debugging-with-javascript/)
- [JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)